# MediaCapture gives poor quality of QR code image captured(Windows Phone 8.1 universal app)

Tags: windows

MediaCapture gives poor quality of QR code image captured, because of which QR code decoder(Zxing) is not able to decode the QR code(Windows Phone 8.1 universal app)
The problem comes only if QR code becomes more complex, i.e. generated out of long string(more then 180 characters), for QR codes generated out of small strings(less then 180) it works fine.

If I feed image directly to Zxing decoder(copy qr image to solution and provide uri) it works fine. But if I capture image using mediacapture api await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

and feed it to decoder it does not work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the image you posted in the comments for the other answer in conjunction to the code snippets you're using for focus, I would guess that you're calling the focus API at the wrong time. Make sure to use the FocusControl (and other "auto" controls such as WhiteBalance and Exposure) *after* starting the preview.

Also, focus takes some time to converge, so make sure you're waiting for the operation to finish before capturing a photo.

Comment: thanks mike, yes after getting the focus right, decoder is able to decode the qr code, And one more thing the decoder is working only for low resolution photos(640*480) and (1280*720) and not for high resolution, which is not a problem for me as long as decoder works fine

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CameraResolution SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) on the Microsoft Windows Universal Samples GitHub repo. You should be looking into using the [GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.getavailablemediastreamproperties.aspx) method, pick the resolution you want to use, and set it on the MediaStreamType of your choosing (Video, Photo, Preview) by using the [SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700895.aspx) method.

Do read through the full sample, though. There are some details (like the number of MediaStreamTypes supported by the camera, see [VideoDeviceCharacteristic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapturesettings.videodevicecharacteristic)) that you should understand to build a robust camera app.

Comment: hi mike thanks for the reply,
I had already tried resolution selection.But I still face the same issue. Image captured still seems to be of low quality for QR code decoder.

Comment: Could it be that the image is out of focus? The CameraManualControls sample demonstrates how to set up continuous autofocus.

Comment: yes I am setting autofocus alsoFocusSettings focusSetting = new FocusSettings()
                {
                    Mode = FocusMode.Continuous,
                    AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange,
                    DisableDriverFallback = false,
                    WaitForFocus = true,                    
                };

Comment: Share a comparison image in your question, because it's difficult to imagine what else could be causing the "low quality" without seeing what's going on.

Comment: captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSetting);

Comment: I'd like to see a picture, a photo captured by your app. One that Zxing is having trouble decoding.

Comment: I use https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/   to generate qr code from a given string and then try to scan it using windows phone(8.1), My app can scan qr code for smaller strings(length around 200 chars)  but more then that it fails to decode.
But when I used Bing vision to scan the same QR code it works fine, Bing vision is able scan qr code generated out of strings of length even more then 3k

Comment: Sorry, but if I can't see a picture of such an image that can't be decoded by your app, I can't help you. Upload a photo.

Comment: hi mike
i have uploaded image here http://www.filedropper.com/photo_11
Result is same even if I rotate the image and give to zxing

Comment: That photo is out of focus, I think getting the focus right should be your top priority. For ease of download, image is re-uploaded here: http://i.imgur.com/GePLdcZ.png